Issues with Git repository: broken links, dangling objects, and parsing errors
I'm having issues with my Git repository, including broken links, dangling objects, and parsing errors when running git fsck --full.
Here are the details:
organic@web:~/dev/docker-wordpress-caddy/m208$ sudo git fsck --full && sudo git gc --prune=now && sudo git fetch origin && sudo git merge origin/main && sudo git push --force origin main && sudo git config --global --add safe.directory /home/organic/dev/docker-wordpress-caddy/m208
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (126502/126502), done.
broken link from  commit 637baaabc596726b36419a3a9afccc51b208d856
              to  commit 40aef486a77869d1110fc52e7a7c780ff86f2295
dangling blob 4135d8aaafc07d4f41995edff1d712d9b13ff4c7
missing commit 40aef486a77869d1110fc52e7a7c780ff86f2295
    dangling blob 7ff52c0679c487402be9ac80c1cd2af92bd9c319
    dangling blob 3c6e51010606936f19df210738a636db23cf60aa
    dangling blob f4a2b168ccb959d824ffe45ed99607562efbbffe
    dangling blob 20a42941d1a6ac09996f4aa14e1d3bf7800ff2c6
    dangling blob 1fa8e92668ff4e4409ac027f7dd31f1be061c1d7
    dangling blob bba9cd7f5ab2d60375ae59a1867c88f3eaf6b9e2
    dangling blob 6cc27968aa8472dcd3b1e67ef255c60652a08244
    dangling blob 8bfa1545f52cfaa5536c17d8ea9115000a97a444
    dangling blob a3fc79cb6ebe3c0e992c126cb688c49ed638782a
    dangling blob c78b7ea32763743eb3da569aba4b57c33cee4d3d
    dangling blob b0ddf2d894b108ed02366553e99ab5d5ad037278
    dangling blob 2753af6b5bb9d5de3bf911a11e01cedcbd52fe09
    error: Could not read 01c05eb6aac12debda0f5faa126f176ec222c22e
    failed to parse commit 01c05eb6aac12debda0f5faa126f176ec222c22e from object database for commit-graph
    error: Could not read 03c5bf83d1ea08786754bafc1614d3277a2748ed
    failed to parse commit 03c5bf83d1ea08786754bafc1614d3277a2748ed from object database for commit-graph
    error: Could not read 043e3ec06c44ce770a023ceef61ff09cdf648176
    failed to parse commit 043e3ec06c44ce770a023ceef61ff09cdf648176 from object database for commit-graph
    error: Could not read 04dddf24a19e02503281a27ad673213a3f7ec6b4
    failed to parse commit 04dddf24a19e02503281a27ad673213a3f7ec6b4 from object database for commit-graph
    error: Could not read 05ad5b016930f9020c9ab7724309bf4b90ae3303
    failed to parse commit 05ad5b016930f9020c9ab7724309bf4b90ae3303 from object database for commit-graph
...
...
failed to parse commit fdd30f66c61acf5abce03ebcb55a2a0408827444 from object database for commit-graph
error: Could not read ffbc10791a4f2b64aea853fccc5ce574af46b825
failed to parse commit ffbc10791a4f2b64aea853fccc5ce574af46b825 from object database for commit-graph
error: Could not read ffc75ea1e663fcb28b0b4d68a3c88f6760af40f9
failed to parse commit ffc75ea1e663fcb28b0b4d68a3c88f6760af40f9 from object database for commit-graph
Verifying commits in commit graph: 100% (235/235), done.

Troubleshooting Steps:

Removed corrupted objects using git fsck --unreachable | xargs git prune.
Rebuilt the commit-graph using git commit-graph write.
Fetched remote changes using git fetch origin.
Merged remote changes with local branch using git merge origin/main.
Force pushed changes to remote repository using git push --force origin main.

However, the issues persist, and I'm unable to push my changes to the remote repository without encountering errors.
Additional Context:

Operating System: Ubuntu 23.10
Git version: 2.40.1


Why are you using sudo git? AFAIK, there's no reason to use git as root.

@wjandrea thanks so much. You're absolutely right. Unfortunately I had to use these commands with sudo when I encountered some issues with privileges when ran some commands, but I'll investigate it further in my spare time.
